# React GraphQL & ApolloServer: Unhandled Rejection (Error): GraphQL error: Cannot access 'post' before initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, graphql, react-apollo

I have a simple social media app that uses: GraphQL & ApolloServer as a backend where users can like posts. But an error occurs when a user who isn't logged in tries to like a button and an error called:

Unhandled Rejection (Error): GraphQL error: Authorization header must be provided

occurs.

This is the code for the likePost mutation...

```
    async likePost(_, { postId }, context) {
  const { username } = checkAuth(context);

  const post = await Post.findById(postId);
  if (post) {
    if (post.likes.find((like) => like.username === username)) {

      post.likes = post.likes.filter((like) => like.username !== username);
    } else {
      post.likes.push({
        username,
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
      });
    }

    await post.save();
    return post;
  } else throw new UserInputError('Post not found');
}
```

},

This is the code for checking authorization file.

```
   const { AuthenticationError } = require('apollo-server');

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { SECRET_KEY } = require('../config');

module.exports = (context) => {
  // context = { ... headers }
  const authHeader = context.req.headers.authorization;
  if (authHeader) {
    // Bearer ....
    const token = authHeader.split('Bearer ')[1];
    if (token) {
      try {
        const user = jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY);
        return user;
      } catch (err) {
        throw new AuthenticationError('Invalid/Expired token');
      }
    }
    throw new Error("Authentication token must be 'Bearer [token]");
  }
```

throw new Error('Authorization header must be provided');
};

How do I go about solving this problem so that no error comes up when an unregistered user tries to like a post?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to this video to build the social media app (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1mdAPFq2Os&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org). You might get this error because of the Button component in the LikeButton.js file.

```
<Button as='div' labelPosition='right' onClick={likePost}>
     <CustomPopup content={liked? 'unlike post': 'like post'}>
          {likeButton} 
     </CustomPopup>
</Button>
```

This Button component will execute the onClick method you specified (not the `'/login'` path specified in the `{likeButton}`) which is doing the mutation of the database and which will need a authorization header to do it. Therefore, when you are not login (no authorization header) but click on the like button, you will get an error.

And here is how I modified:

```
return(
        user? (
            <Button as='div' labelPosition='right' onClick={likePost}>
                <CustomPopup content={liked? 'unlike post': 'like post'}>
                {likeButton} 
                </CustomPopup>
            </Button>
        ):(
            <Button labelPosition='right' as='a' href='/login'>
                <CustomPopup content={liked? 'unlike post': 'like post'}>
                {likeButton} 
                </CustomPopup>
            </Button>
        )
        
);
```